# How to remove query param with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I know we can replace query params in component based classes doing something along the lines of:

```
  componentDidMount() {       
    const { location, replace } = this.props;   

    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);   
    if (queryParams.has('error')) { 
      this.setError(    
        'There was a problem.'  
      );    
      queryParams.delete('error');  
      replace({ 
        search: queryParams.toString(), 
      });   
    }   
  }
```

Is there a way to do it with react hooks in a functional component?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

For React Router V6 and above, see [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73353425/2873538).

---

**Original Answer:**

Yes, you can use [`useHistory`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) & [`useLocation`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hooks from react-router:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Foo() {
  const [error, setError] = useState('')

  const location = useLocation()
  const history = useHistory()

  useEffect(() => {
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
    
    if (queryParams.has('error')) {
      setError('There was a problem.')
      queryParams.delete('error')
      history.replace({
        search: queryParams.toString(),
      })
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>Component</>
  )
}
```

As `useHistory()` returns [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) object which has `replace` function which can be used to replace the current entry on the history stack.

And `useLocation()` returns [location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) object which has `search` property containing the URL query string e.g. `?error=occurred&foo=bar"` which can be converted into object using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API (which is not supported in IE).

Comment: This won't work with Class Component, how to we handle it there.

Comment: In a class component, replace `useEffect` with `componentDidMount`, `useState` with `this.state`, `useHistory` with `this.props.history` + `withRouter` HOC. That should work with class component.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, to be used with function components I've created a library `useClearParams` https://github.com/oyalhi/use-clear-params#readme

Comment: useNavigate in react-router-dom v6

Comment: I've used this approach to update a search param based on user selection on the page, but this causes page reload, which is completely unnecessary in my case ...

Answer (score 36):

Use `useSearchParams` hook.

```
import {useSearchParams} from 'react-router-dom';

export const App =() => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const removeErrorParam = () => {
    if (searchParams.has('error')) {
      searchParams.delete('error');
      setSearchParams(searchParams);
    }
  }

  return <button onClick={removeErrorParam}>Remove error param</button>
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't remove it from the url (which might be a little confusing depending on the use case) - useHistory is no more in v6 - so some variation of useNavigation would probably be needed... know how to navigate without triggering a re-render?

If I recall last time I needed prevention of navigation I messed with navigator from UNSAFE_NavigationContext

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70700037/2848941 hmm .... seems extra navigation _shouldn't_ be necessary, as long as it's in a useEffect?

Comment: Added this to my useEffect hook and it works like a charm.

Comment: is this still in react router v6?

Comment: This removes the query param from the URL in my app (react-router v6.10) without using useNavigate or useEffect