# How to remove Query Params

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

How can I remove or update query params without refreshing the page in Next JS (React)?

1. The user is on the URL `/about?login=success&something=yes`
2. Click a button and removes `?login=success&something=yes` from the URL without refreshing the page. The URL after clicking the button will be `/about`

How can I achieve it?

As mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032050/how-to-remove-query-param-with-react-hooks), I know that is possible to remove query params or query strings with Router. But, `useLocation` and `useHistory` are not avaliable on `next/router`.

Comment: does window.history.replaceState work for you? I tried it too, but when query params exist, next.js will force the url to revert

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState), you can using `history.replaceState` to implement this.

```js
window.history.replaceState(null, '', '/about')
```

Comment: Yess, this solution works. Thanks, I'll also add `if (typeof window !== "undefined") { window.history.replaceState(null, '', '/about') }`

Comment: I tried this solution, the url change is reverted

Comment: this solution works but it make problem with back button.

Comment: apologies, but this is not a solution i would recommend

Comment: I recommend to you, use useRouter : 
router.replace('/about', undefined, { shallow: true })

Comment: I don't get why this answer is marked as the correct one, it makes no use of next router

Answer (score 74):

You can use `next/router` to remove the query params in the URL.

```js
const router = useRouter();

router.replace('/about', undefined, { shallow: true });
```

Use `replace` to prevent adding a new URL entry into the history (otherwise just use `push`), and `shallow: true` allows you to [change the URL without running data fetching methods](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing). This will cause a re-render but will not refresh the page per se.

---

The above solution will remove all query parameters from the URL. If you want to only remove a specific parameter you can use the code below instead.

```js
const removeQueryParam = (param) => {
    const { pathname, query } = router;
    const params = new URLSearchParams(query);
    params.delete(param);
    router.replace(
        { pathname, query: params.toString() },
        undefined, 
        { shallow: true }
    );
};

removeQueryParam('something');
```

Comment: I tried this solution before, but it triggers a page refresh 

Comment: Usually you want to `keep pathname and all other queries and delete just one query param` - if you want to do that check my answer for this questions bellow.

Comment: the shortest solution was to 
const router = useRouter();

delete router.query.something;
router.push(router)

Comment: The scond solution is missing `router` in the function argument. Also TS complains about `new URLSearchParams(query)` (using router with type `NextRouter`. To be precisee the error is : `Argument of type 'ParsedUrlQuery' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[][] | Record<string, string> | URLSearchParams'.`

Answer (score 7):

my solution to similiar problem of mine is this:

```
push(`${asPath.split('?')[0]}?comp=${id}`);
```

or if you want to have reusable function:

```
function delQuery(asPath) {
  return asPath.split('?')[0]
}

...
const {push, asPath} = useRouter()

push(`${delQuery(asPath)}?comp=${id}`);
```

Answer (score 6):

You usually want to `keep pathname and all other query params` the same while deleting one specific query param (in example `shouldRefetchUser`) you can do so like this:

```
const router = useRouter()
const { pathname, query } = router
delete router.query.shouldRefetchUser
router.replace({ pathname, query }, undefined, { shallow: true })
```

(Upgraded answer of @juliomalves)

Comment: It's >= 2023 now, and you want to do this in Next >= 13 and above - if you want to do that check my answer for this questions below.

Answer (score 5):

If you want remove single or multiple params from query,

```js
const router = useRouter();

/**
 * If removeList is empty, the function removes all params from url.
 * @param {*} router 
 * @param {*} removeList 
 */
const removeQueryParamsFromRouter = (router, removeList = []) => {
    if (removeList.length > 0) {
        removeList.forEach((param) => delete router.query[param]);
    } else {
        // Remove all
        Object.keys(router.query).forEach((param) => delete router.query[param]);
    }
    router.replace(
        {
            pathname: router.pathname,
            query: router.query
        },
        undefined,
        /**
         * Do not refresh the page
         */
        { shallow: true }
    );
};

const anyFunction = () => {
    // "/about?firstParam=5&secondParam=10"
    removeQueryParamsFromRouter(router, ['myParam']);
    // "/about?secondParam=10"
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use "*router.push*" or "*router.replace*" with "*shallow: true*", this will remove the query param without reloading the page.

```
const router = useRouter();
router.replace('/about', undefined, { shallow: true });
```

Or if you want to delete single query then this quick and easy method will help you

> eg. /about?login=success&something=yes

```
const router = useRouter();
// perform this inside function call or button click etc
delete router.query.something;
router.push(router)
```

now the updated route will be

> /about?login=success

Comment: This was my solution too, seems like the simplest and cleanest one out there and works well.

Answer (score 3):

For next/router, along with typescript, none of the above answers seem to be working anymore.

The following snippet takes all query parameters and removes one by the key while keeping all others untouched.

```
const { push, query } = useRouter();


const removeQueryParam = (param) => {
    const updatedQuery = query;
    delete updatedQuery[param];

    push({ query: updatedQuery }, undefined, { shallow: true });
}
```

Usage (in clickHandler or wherever):

```
removeQueryParam('queryParamName');
```

Note: Use `router.replace` instead of `router.push` if you don't want to add the new URL to the browser history back stack.

Answer (score 3):

For Next 13 & above, you usually want to keep pathname and all other query params the same while deleting one specific query param (in example shouldRefetchUser) you can do so like this:

```
import { useRouter, usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

const router = useRouter()
const pathname = usePathname()
const searchParams = useSearchParams()

const nextSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString())
nextSearchParams.delete('shouldRefetchUser')

router.replace(`${pathname}?${nextSearchParams}`)
```

(Upgraded answer of @sebastian-voráč-msc)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution will be a bit more neat:

```
const { query, replace } = useRouter();
const setActiveTab = useCallback((tabName: string) => {
    const { group, ...paramsExceptGroup } = query || {};
    replace(
      {
        query: tabName === defaultTabName ? paramsExceptGroup : { ...paramsExceptGroup, group: tabName },
      },
      undefined,
      { shallow: true },
    ).then();
  }, [query, defaultTabName]);
```

So if "tab" is default, I drop it with spread operator and remove it from query.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `useRouter` hook from `next/router` to access the current route and query parameters. **To remove or update parameters without refreshing the page, we can use the `push` method of the router object**.

Here is an example of how we can remove query parameters from the URL:

```
const router = useRouter();
  function removeQueryHandler() {
    const { pathname } = router;

    router.push({ pathname });
}
```

**CodeSandbox**: [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/confident-northcutt-n3lcth?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A30%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A11%2C%22startColumn%22%3A30%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A11%7D%5D)

**Another Approach**:

**We can use shallow routing as well to remove or update query parameters without triggering a full page refresh in Next.js. Like this**:

```
function removeQueryHandler() {
    const { pathname } = router;

    router.push({ pathname }, undefined, { shallow: true });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove query param from router object by []:

```
const router = useRouter();
router.query.something = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {NextRouter} from 'next/router'

export const removeQueryParams = (
  router: NextRouter,
  paramsToRemove: Array<string> = []
) => {
  if (paramsToRemove.length > 0) {
    paramsToRemove.forEach((param) => delete router.query[param])
  } else {
    // Remove all query parameters
    Object.keys(router.query).forEach((param) => delete router.query[param])
  }
  router.replace(
    {
      pathname: router.pathname,
      query: router.query,
    },
    undefined,
    /**
     * Do not refresh the page when the query params are removed
     */
    {shallow: true}
  )
}
const anyFunction = () => {
    // "/about?firstParam=5&secondParam=10"
    removeQueryParamsFromRouter(router, ['myParam']);
    // "/about?secondParam=10"
};
```

[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70186040/13053036)

The original answer mentioned here throws an error as the object is undefined, also it is the typescript version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Good way to do it when you know the query param you want to remove based on https://github.com/jbranchaud/til/blob/master/nextjs/remove-a-query-param-from-the-url.md

```
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
    // extract the value from the query params
    const { someKey, ...updatedQuery } = router.query;
    
    // create an updated router path object
    const newPathObject = {
      pathname: router.pathname,
      query: updatedQuery,
    };
    
    // update the URL, without re-triggering data fetching
    void router.push(newPathObject, undefined, { shallow: true });

  }, [router]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you well:

```
router.replace('/about', undefined, { shallow: true });
```

The shallow routing will not cause page refresh and data refetch. Learn more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing).

Even though the above solution removes the query params without causing a refresh, they do cause **re-render**.

Unfortunately, Nextjs has no built in solution to remove query param without causing a re-render. But, there's a native solution:

```
window.history.replaceState({ ...window.history.state, as: '/about', url: '/about' }, '', '/about');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `router.query` is a simple object, you can delete query params by mutating `router.query`.

Lets say you have query params `?size=M&color=red`:

```
// INIT

const router = useRouter();
router.push({ 
  pathname: router.pathname, 
  query: { ...router.query, color: "red", size: "M" }
},
  undefined, 
  {}
);
```

And you need to remove only **ONE** param, for example `size=M`.
All you need to do is directly delete the field from `router.query` object and push your mutation (spread operator to keep all other params):

```
// DELETE ONE

delete router.query.color;
router.push({
  pathname: router.pathname,
  query: { ...router.query }
},
  undefined,
  {}
);
```

If you want to remove **ALL** params, just simply push `null` to `query` field:

```
// DELETE ALL

router.push({
  pathname: router.pathname,
  query: null
},
  undefined,
  {}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Next 13+, if you're working with the `app` router, you'll have to use a combination of `useSearchParams`, `usePathname`, `URLSearchParams`, and `useRouter` from `next/navigation` to achieve this.

```js
import { usePathname, useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

const router = useRouter();
const pathname = usePathname();
const query = useSearchParams();

const params = new URLSearchParams(query);

//do your modifications on search params
params.delete("search");

const newUrl = `${pathname}?${params.toString()}`;
router.replace(newUrl);
```

[Reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#updating-searchparams).

Answer (score 0):

My case is canonical url, so should be available on build, the approach:

```
const router = useRouter();
const url = new URL(PUBLIC_URL + router.asPath);
const canonicalUrl = PUBLIC_URL + url.pathname;
```

*note: this using `pages`*

Answer (score -2):

Nextjs has `useRouter` hook which can be used to changed url programmatically.
[Link to the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router).

Comment: Yep, I know about useRouter  but which value should I change? and how?