# Fail to use history.replaceState in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I export Next.js as static files and let backend code handle them. What I need is just to remove query params in the current URL. I used to use

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname)
```

When there are no query params, replaceState works, but when query params exist, soon the url is changed back. What is causing this?
I am using a custom server, so 'next/router' doesn't help, it only reload the page.

Here is an example,

suppose my current path is `/home`, I can call `window.history.replaceState(null, null, '/home1')` to change path to `/home1`. But if path is like `/home?a=123`, after replaceState is called, the url revert to `/home?a=123` right away.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please? Also, have you had a look at [NEXT JS - How to remove Query Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606974/next-js-how-to-remove-query-params)?

Comment: @juliomalves just open any nextjs page with query params, like `localhost:3000/home?a=1`. then call history.replaceState with any pathname. You can see the url is changed and revert to `localhost:3000/home?a=1` right away. The solution in the post doesn't work for me.

Comment: @juliomalves if run history.replaceState in console, there will be no problem, but I called in useEffect

Comment: I do what you are doing and it works flawlessly inside useEffect on exported next pages. However, you might want to use [router.replace](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreplace) to do things properly

Comment: @Mr.Hedgehog I created a new nextjs app and run in dev mode, still got this error, do you have query params in your url? router.replace doesn't help me since it reloads the page.

Answer (score 2):

In Next.js it's best to use `router.replace(window.location.pathname, undefined, { shallow: true })`, where `shallow: true` updates the URL without the page refreshing.