# How to drop the query parameters after a redirect with NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In NextJS,
how can I use redirect to turn URL like `/page?foo=bar` into `/page/bar` ?

I read https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects but couldn't find a solution.

What I have today is:

```
{
   source: '/page',
   has: [
       { 
          type: 'query',
          key: 'foo'
       }
   ],
   destination: '/page/:foo',
   permanent: true
}
```

but that make `/page?foo=bar` into `/page/bar?foo=bar`.

How can I drop the query ?

**Edit:**

So I realized that this doesn't event work at all with Netlify.

I tried to follow https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/ but I have the same problem with the query parameters staying.

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [NEXT JS - How to remove Query Params?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65611918/1870780)? You could remove the params on the client-side with `next/router`.

Comment: I wanted a redirect that would convert the caught parameter as expected. The behavior is weird right now

Comment: Your question is so cool, for these kinds of problems I always make a wrapper function for routes and use it for anywhere I want to route.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware).

Just parse the query parameter yourself and add redirection.

Store a file `_middleware.ts` below the pages directory:

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;
    
    if (// Your-thing ) 
        return NextResponse.redirect(//Your-url);

    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Maybe there is a different way, I don't know, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

At least when using Vercel, you can archive this by repeating the parameters from the `has` in the `destination` but leaving the value empty.

E.g.:

```
{
   source: '/page',
   has: [
       { 
          type: 'query',
          key: 'foo'
       }
   ],
   destination: '/page/:foo?foo=',
   permanent: true
}
```

Parameters that already exit in the `destination` won't be copied over and parameters with an empty value in the `destination` will be removed completely.