# Next JS 12, redirects problem. how to get rid of query param in destination?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This is my scenario :
there is a source URL like this: shop/Paypal?page=2
I want to  redirect to a destination that does not need any query param, like this: http://localhost:3000/shop/visacard/

I tried these two solutions:
1 - adding query matching like this :

```js
has: [
  {
    type: "query",
    key: "page",
  },
]
```

but the problem is page param appears in the destination which I don't want.

2- secondly I tried to add `\\` to my URL according to next js docs to ignore the Regex character and my URL was like this:  shop/paypal\?page=2
in this solution, the project runs normally but redirecting does not work at all.

Comment: Hi Mehdi! Sorry, but in its current state, your question might get downvoted or closed. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking so people can help you better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NEXT JS - How to remove Query Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606974/next-js-how-to-remove-query-params)