# React Router Dom - Clear url parameters without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-parameters

I do have some parameters passed by a link to an url, like :

```
https://mysite/post/list?success
```

Considering I'm with **React JS** and using **React router dom**, how should I do to clean the parameters **without refreshing the page**, in order to be back button friendly ? I'm aiming for the same page, without params.

Edit : Proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032050/how-to-remove-query-param-with-react-hooks), this solution **does not work** for this case

```
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
  queryParams.delete('success')
  history.replace({
    search: queryParams.toString(),
  })
```

It **does** work while treating params case to case (by applying "if" chains), but I'm searching for a function **clearing them all at once** - is there a way to do that with the .delete method ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove query param with react hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032050/how-to-remove-query-param-with-react-hooks)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'd try to clear the whole params and not a single and defined string, so the .delete() is not doing its work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it !

```
   const queryParams = ""
   history.replace({
     search: queryParams,
   })
```

'Twas dead simple and efficient. Closing.